# Display related content in view by entity reference in views drupal 7

Tags: entities, views

I want to show related content title in block view by entity reference. I have created two content type 1)Hotel Type  2)Room Type. Room Type have field_hotel which references to Hotel Type. 
How cant I show content title of Room Type in block except current node.

for eg. RoomA, RoomB, RoomC are belongs to HotelX. I want show link of RoomB and RoomC on page RoomA

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use

- [Corresponding Entity References](https://drupal.org/project/cer) for Drupal 7

That way, current node will reference all nodes that reference it - and from this point creating a [view](https://drupal.org/project/views) is trivial - or **you can simply display the field** created for back reference, *without need for a views module at all*.

**Other way is to use Views**. Create a view displaying nodes from content type A, add argument *content reference field > provide default argument > node ID from URL* and display this block view on the nodes from content type B.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, below article help me to complete my task. http://ericgilbertsen.com/2013/06/create-related-content-blocks-drupal-7-views-entity-reference/